# React Native Expo Sharing not work on IOS

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, sharing

I have a code in React Native Expo in which I generate a report pdf and I want to share it.

On android the app works perfectly, not on ios. When I press to share, it opens the tab with the sharing options and closes at the same time.

I've already researched, I've used the documentation and the gpt chat and nothing solves it, please help me!

```
async function exportPDF(cliente: any, propriedade: any, talhao: any, safra: any) {
if (!checkIfSavedCalculationsIsEmpty()) {

      const htmlContent = await createPDFContent(cliente, propriedade, talhao, safra);
    
      const options = {
        html: htmlContent,
        base64: true,
      };
    
      try {
        const pdf = await Print.printToFileAsync(options);
    
        if (pdf.uri) {
          const destinationUri = `${FileSystem.documentDirectory}${nameFile}.pdf`;
    
          await FileSystem.moveAsync({
            from: pdf.uri,
            to: destinationUri,
          });
    
          const shareOptions = {
            url: `file://${destinationUri}`,
            mimeType: 'application/pdf',
            UTI: 'com.adobe.pdf',
          };
    
          await Sharing.shareAsync(destinationUri, shareOptions);
        } else {
          alert('Erro ao salvar o PDF');
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Erro ao gerar o PDF:', error);
      }
    
    }

}
```

I've tried passing the pdf.uri directly to the Sharing.shareAsync function, I've tried removing the 'file://' from the url, but nothing works.